# DeepRequired<T> with Shift<T> not assignable

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to write a utility that can set deep keys of an object as required.

#### What works

So far, I have come up with a way to get all possible `Leaves` of an object, which I want to use for the path validation. It collects all key paths into arrays, but stops at optional keys to come around the infinite depth issue.

Then, I also made `DeepRequired`, which sets properties to required based on the passed leaves:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  father?: Person;
  mother?: Person;
  siblings?: Person[];
  contact: {
    email: string;
  };
  created_at: Date;
};

type PersonLeaves = Leaves<Person>;
// type PersonLeaves = ["name"] | ["father"] | ["mother"] | ["siblings"] | ["contact", "email"];

type PersonWithParents = DeepRequired<Person, ["father" | "mother"]>;
// type PersonWithParents = {
//   name: string;
//   father: Person; // Note how this is now required
//   mother: Person; // Note how this is now required
//   siblings?: Person[];
//   contact: {
//     email: string;
//   };
//   created_at: Date;
// }

type PersonWithFatherSiblings = DeepRequired<DeepRequired<Person, ["father"]>, ["father", "siblings"]>;
// type PersonWithFatherSiblings = {
//   name: string;
//   father: PersonWithSiblings; // Father is required, then father's siblings is required.
//   mother?: Person;
//   siblings?: Person[];
//   contact: {
//     email: string;
//   };
//   created_at: Date;
// }
```

#### The issue

The utilities all seem to work as intended, but I do get an error at `Shift` in my `DeepRequired` definition, and I'm not getting any paths suggestions in vscode when writing a type using `DeepRequired`.

```
Type 'Shift<P>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Leaves<T[K]>'.
  Type 'unknown[] | []' is not assignable to type 'Leaves<T[K]>'.
    Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Leaves<T[K]>'.
```

I am trying to figure out why is this happening. Could somebody help improve this?

#### TL;DR

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwMYENgB4AqUIA9gQIAmAzlCgiADRQCCO+hp5lA2gLoB8UAvFK5hoA6EbXYBuALAAoGaEhQAygAsAlgDMM2PAWJkKIDtz7bGe-geEjVCdRABOddlAD8dKAC5+EmXPDQAeTBgVUQUABsAaQgQEiwGXWY4ACMAKwgkYGMoAG8ZKH5IqBsoAGsYuHUoTHYAWhcvU0SyACUMuHsidEiaTFZIrlcoBAgANwdPKEipaQBfVnKQSuqfWWl5aAAZCBRxuMxspqYyAAobO0cAVQBKDnyh7d2IOMvOe8aE46gU9Mz7tzy0gKwMKxQQZQqVRq9S8RR0XyCITCURi+zeQJBwLc-XY90xk3gyDQ3Rojz2WBxnE4MxB80Wyxq728Mz8CgAIhAIGA2gBHACuqnsEC6gigAAVPuYyc8sFTeNVJUk0hlgP8oAEALaqLQ0ACi+HsKEy6HpUJoYtYAAYuNwAGR44G8gVCroOkGA-Eg-pgqD64CG42m6rmq1cdheDlcp2C4UUgY0FQaDBiqk0z2zN1QdEFRos9b+cUOEiIeUe4YoDUQLwkf02ADmafUaGUDgahfsxYQaY1cGALfsbbFRcQaZIqmS4XrJEHw4QHDTSEQwCNwC8ZYKEA1KFU4WrtYQDfuswXQrQwoA+mgI2eZsffPmFEOO4hpWQ+K-0E-O9T7xt252AHVtWUMUUCFBBgDfKBI25CB+RjLov0QGhWAAIibPsHFQqAAB8oFQntMPsVCuDzP8kIQIC+wAMWbBxFHHScDygmDoxddBWLg51YwolD0Lo4iuD4jD+1QmhULHCcpxIn9pCAA) to see the working example with the error

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if it work for you:

```js
type Concat<T extends any, A extends any[]> = [T, ...A];

type Shift<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer _, ...infer A] ? A : [];

type OptionalKeys<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K;
}[keyof T];


type Leaves<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? Leaves<U>
  : T extends object
  ? {
    [K in keyof T]-?: K extends OptionalKeys<T>
    ? [K]
    : Concat<K, Leaves<T[K]>>;
  }[keyof T]
  : [];

type DeepRequired<T, P extends Leaves<T>> = T extends object
  ? Omit<T, Extract<keyof T, P[0]>> &
  Required<
    {
                                     // Shift did not satisfied constraint, so I added condition
      [K in Extract<keyof T, P[0]>]: Shift<P> extends Leaves<T[K]> ? DeepRequired<T[K], Shift<P>> : never
    }
  >
  : T;

type Person = {
  name: string;
  father?: Person;
  mother?: Person;
  siblings?: Person[];
  contact: {
    email: string;
  };
  created_at: Date;
};

type PersonLeaves = Leaves<Person>;

type PersonWithParents = DeepRequired<Person, ["father" | "mother"]>;

type PersonWithFatherSiblings = DeepRequired<DeepRequired<Person, ["father"]>, ["father", "siblings"]>;
```